# Visualizing relational database such as Nycflights13 in R

Tags: r

I am trying to visualize the common variables in various datasets in `Nycflights13` package. My question is, how to visualize the connections as shown in this book https://r4ds.had.co.nz/relational-data.html.

Or how can we get the common variable names in all the sets with a small code?

```r
vcdExtra::datasets("nycflights13")
#> Loading package: nycflights13
#>       Item      class       dim               Title
#> 1 airlines data.frame      16x2      Airline names.
#> 2 airports data.frame    1458x8    Airport metadata
#> 3  flights data.frame 336776x19        Flights data
#> 4   planes data.frame    3322x9     Plane metadata.
#> 5  weather data.frame  26115x15 Hourly weather data
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: If you meant a variable name that exist in all those datasets, it is not there.  If you want to get variables common in more than one dataset, `vcdExtra::datasets("nycflights13") %>% pull(Item) %>% mget(inherits = TRUE) %>% map(names) %>% enframe %>%unnest(value) %>% count(value)`

Comment: @akrun I got this error. Error: value for ‘airlines’ not found

Comment: ``` r
purrr::map(vcdExtra::datasets("nycflights13")$Item,\(x)names(x))
#> Loading package: nycflights13
#> [[1]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> NULL
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: You may need to install `nycflights13` package